# Abstract Factory with optional ctor argument without variadic templates

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I have an Classic Abstract Factory Implementation which I would like to provide with an optional constructor argument. Thema answer seemed simple using variadic templates but I'm stuck with VS2010 which doesn't support it. So at least one argument like this:

```
template <class IFTYPE, typename IDTYPE=std::string, typename Args=void >
class AbstractFactory {
  typdef std::shared_ptr<IFTYPE> (*CreateFunc)(Args);
  public:
  std::shared_ptr<IFTYPE> create( IDTYPE id, Args args ) { 
    return nullptr;
  }
};
```

The problem is I can't handle the default type in the `create` method for `void`. Since I can't name an argument `void`.

How can I get around this while keeping the option for different argument types? Partial specialisation should not work since it would change the signature of `create`. What options do I have here?

Thank you...

Comment: Do you consider an option of wrapping args into a tuple (boost::tuple should work, I belive). So that an empty set of arguments would become a boost:tuple<>, which is valid for overloading.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean with "Partial specialisation should not work since it would change the signature of `create`". Every different `Args` change the signature of `create()`. Exactly, what signature for `crate()` do you want in `void` case?

Comment: Not entirely clear what you intend to do here, e.g., why can't you partially specialize? Add an example, of how you intend to use `AbstractFactory`! If you really must have `create(IDTYPE, Args)`, consider making a `class DummyArgs` which just has a default constructor but does nothing (and default the argument `Args args=Args()` of `create`).

Comment: I implmented something like that with C++98. See https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/SmlParser/blob/master/include/factory.hpp. Maybe it fits your needs.